# Why I can't pass parameter into .then function (AngularJS)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this function

```
$scope.updateValue = function(key, selectedProductname, numberUsed){

var selectedKey = key;
var selectedProductname = selectedProductname;
var numberUsed = numberUsed;

var useageRef = ref.child('/useage/');
var updateObj = $firebase(useageRef);

var myData = {
    productName : selectedProductname,
    numberUsed : numberUsed
}

var decrementLocation = inventoryRef.child(key + '/amount')

updateObj.$push(myData).then(

    decrementLocation.transaction(function (current_value, numberUsed) {
           console.log(numberUsed);
          return (current_value || 0) - 1;

})

    );  
}
```

I pass "numberUsed" into $scope.updateValue and use it inside myData and then push it to the server and there is no problem with that but when I use it at this line "decrementLocation.transaction(function (current_value, numberUsed) {" and then I try to console.log(numberUsed); the console says undefined. Why? and how can I use numberUsed in this line "decrementLocation.transaction(function (current_value, numberUsed) {" ? how to code it successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a number of things going on here.

First of all, in the following code:

```
    decrementLocation.transaction(function (current_value, numberUsed) {
       console.log(numberUsed);
      return (current_value || 0) - 1;
    })
```

You are re-declaring `numberUsed` as the second parameter of the `.transaction()` callback function. Thus, whatever `numberUsed` was outside of this small function **does not matter**. If you want to use the var from the surrounding function, you would need to do:

```
    decrementLocation.transaction(function (current_value) {
       console.log(numberUsed);
      return (current_value || 0) - 1;
    })
```

Second of all, there is no closing `;` to your `.transaction()` function. I don't think it will materially affect your operating here, but cannot be sure. This should be run through jslint/jshint.

Third, you are redeclaring `numberUsed` inside the entire surrounding `$scope.updateValue()` function.

```
$scope.updateValue = function(key, selectedProductname, numberUsed){
    var numberUsed = numberUsed;
```

So you are declaring a new variable `numberUsed`, whose value will be, well, `numberUsed`, but it is a new var, so it should be set to `undefined`. If it is set to anything at all, that would be surprising. If you need the var, then you should do:

```
$scope.updateValue = function(key, selectedProductname, numberUsed){
    var nu2 = numberUsed;
```

or something similar. But even then, why bother to redeclare the var? It is copied by value anyways.

A good linter will catch any of this.

Comment: alright, thank you so much. I have edit everything to be what you have said and it works fine. So, in conclusion when these get passed into: $scope.updateValue = function(key, selectedProductname, numberUsed) the key, selectedProductname and numberUsed are already a variable that I can use anywhere in the function and the function that nested inside it without redeclaring it? Am I understand correctly? ^^

Comment: If you pass them in when you call the function `$scope.updateValue()` then yes.